SQL XML Column into multiple rows
I have a XML column called columnsupdated in a SQL Server table. I'm trying to create a row for each field name that appears in it.
These are a couple examples from the column:
<Fields>
  <Field Name="MiddleName" />
  <Field Name="StatusEffectiveDate" />
  <Field Name="CommitteeActionID" />
</Fields>

<Fields>
  <Field Name="Citizen" />
  <Field Name="StatusTypeID" />
  <Field Name="StatusEffectiveDate" />
</Fields>


While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

And what do you want these rows to contain? Your question is a bit unclear

PLease try the following solution leveraging SQL Server's XQuery.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, columnsupdated XML);
INSERT @tbl (columnsupdated) VALUES
(N'<Fields>
  <Field Name="MiddleName" />
  <Field Name="StatusEffectiveDate" />
  <Field Name="CommitteeActionID" />
</Fields>'),
(N'<Fields>
  <Field Name="Citizen" />
  <Field Name="StatusTypeID" />
  <Field Name="StatusEffectiveDate" />
</Fields>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , c.value('.', 'SYSNAME') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY columnsupdated.nodes('/Fields/Field/@Name') AS t1(c);

Output



id
result




1
MiddleName


1
StatusEffectiveDate


1
CommitteeActionID


2
Citizen


2
StatusTypeID


2
StatusEffectiveDate




Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.
